# Superglobal $_FILES array error element

Tags: php, arrays, file-upload

In the $_FILES array how do you determine what the [error] element means?

It is outputting a 1, which means that it encounters an error, but how can I figure out what error this is, specifically so I can deal with it?

Otherwise I am stuck and the [error] = 1 is kind of useless since it doesn't give me much information about how to remedy the situation.

(basically is there any way to extract more information out of the error array element other then the 1 value that indicates there is an error). If there is no such way to figure out what [error] is, what is another way of figuring out why my file is not uploading properly?

This is what I have tried:

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    //File properties
    $file_name = $file['name'];
    $file_tmp = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $file['size'];
    $file_error = $file['error'];

    //Work out the file extension
    $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
    $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

    $allowed = array('txt', 'jpg', 'mp3', 'mpeg3', 'mpeg', 'mpeg-3', 'zip');

    if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)){
        if($file_error == 0){
            if($file_size <= 10000000){

                $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                $file_destination = 'uploads/' . $file_name_new;

                if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination)){
                    echo $file_destination;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            echo $file_error;
        }
    }
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<br><br>
Click <a href='./member.php'>here</a> to go back to the member page
<br><br>
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($_FILES);
        echo "</pre>";
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is what it outputs for mp3 files:
1

Click here to go back to the member page

Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => soundfile.mp3
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 1
            [size] => 0
        )

)

Answer (score 0):

(1) means : The uploaded file exceeds the upload max filesize. which is 2M and I'm sure your mp3 file size is bigger than that.

To change this directive you have two options :

1 - From php.ini (if you don't know where it is, use phpinfo() function), and change `upload_max_filesize = 16M`, and restart your server.

2 -From your htaccess file : `php_value upload_max_filesize 16M`

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately i already have changed the max file upload side in php.ini file so either i did something wrong or that't not the problem. any other suggestions?

Comment: create a php file and put <?php phpinfo() ?> in it, and check if the value of upload_max_filesize has changed

Comment: ok i did that, and i phpinfo() shows that max file upload size is 2M, which is weird because, in my php.ini file i set it to 15M? why is that? and how can i fix that, so the actual max file upload size is 15M?

Comment: just restart your server